# Can I create multiple full sets with 2^32 data in Redis?

Tags: redis

Actually the question is about the capacity of a single instance of the Redis, regardless of the Memory size.

[The reference said:](https://redis.io/topics/faq#:~:text=Redis%20can%20handle%20up%20to,available%20memory%20in%20your%20system.)

> Redis can handle up to 2^32 keys, and was tested in practice to handle
>   at least 250 million keys per instance. Every hash, list, set, and
>   sorted set, can hold 2^32 elements. In other words your limit is likely
>   the available memory in your system.

So regardless of the server's memory size, Can I create 4 "set" and fill them with almost 2^32 keys in a single instance of Redis? **That means 4*(2^32) keys** by total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets do not contain keys, they [contain strings](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#sets).

> Redis Sets are an unordered collection of Strings.

Of course, your string could happen to share the same characters as one of your keys, but there's nothing special about that. So, yes, you could have four sets containing up to 4 * (2^32) *strings*, but the total number of *keys* would still be limited to 2^32.

Comment: Ops, thanks. You mean the total number of Strings + total of keys + total of lists' items and ... is limited to 2^32? 
Basically you can't store more than 2^32 thing in the Redis?

Comment: @AminShojaei: That 2^32 limit applies to the number of keys, and to the number of elements in *each* collection. The total number of "things" can be greater than 2^32.

Comment: Isn't any limit(except of Memory capacity) for number of things? for example can a single Redis instance support and fill 2 TB of ram and store millions of heavy sets?

I know it's not useful in practice because of performance issue. Just curios.

Comment: @AminShojaei: No, the limit is not based on a total number of "things" in the Redis memory space. The limit is likely due to some kind of 4-byte internal pointer or counter in the Set data structure (for example). Yes, you could have up to 2^32 different sets, each with up to 2^32 different elements.

Comment: Number of things is also limited to that power of two, except messages in a stream (unlimited)

Comment: @ItamarHaber: OK, thanks. Do you have a reference for that limit so I can correct the answer?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry ref: https://redis.io/topics/faq#what-is-the-maximum-number-of-keys-a-single-redis-instance-can-hold-and-what-is-the-max-number-of-elements-in-a-hash-list-set-sorted-set

Comment: @ItamarHaber: Yes, that's the documentation we're discussing, which doesn't mention any such limit. If "every set can hold 2^32 elements" then I could have a Redis instance with two sets, each of which holds 2^32 elements. If that's possible, then the instance contains more than 2^32 "things" (as the term is used by the OP in the comments above); if not, then that's an additional limit not mentioned in the documentation above.